# Why do my uploaded files have 2 file_types?

Tags: php

I added a upload files thing in my messaging system, and when I try to sort the files by file_type it never works.

Here is my upload files function :

```
<?php
session_start();
      include_once "../backend/messaging-functions.php";
      include_once '../backend/databaseconn.php';

      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
      $file_ext= strtolower(end(explode('.',$file_name)));

      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","mp4","MP4","MOV","PNG","JPG","mov","JPEG");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG, PNG or a MP4 file type!";
      }

      if($file_size > 16777216) {
         $errors[]='File size must be at MOST 16 MB!';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true) {
          move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,'../userfiles/'.$file_name);
          $fileplace = '../userfiles/'.$file_name;
            if ($file_type == "image/jpg" or "image/jpeg" or "image/png" or "image/PNG" or "image/JPG" or "image/JPEG") {
            $date = date("y-m-d h:i:s");
            $filetype = "image";
            $myId = $_SESSION['user-id'];
            $message = $fileplace;
            $groupId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
            addMessage($myId, $groupId, $date, $message, $filetype);
          }
            if ($file_type == "video/mp4" or "video/mpeg4") {
              $date = date("y-m-d h:i:s");
              $filedtype = "video";
              $myId = $_SESSION['user-id'];
              $message = $fileplace;
              $groupId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
              addMessage($myId, $groupId, $date, $message, $filedtype);
            }
      }


 ?>
```

I tried adding an exit();  thing after the first if so that it doesn't trigger twice but instead it just never calls itself a video. Please help

Comment: I'm unclear what the issue, and where the issue is. Please clarify. Your `date` also is not valid for mysql so you must be using varchar or some non date column, you should change that. Additionally you should parameterize your query, you haven't escaped everything and likely are injectable.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, is that this `if ($file_type == "video/mp4" or "video/mpeg4")` isn't a valid expression; the latter isn't that is.

Comment: I don't understand Funk Forty Niner, and don't worry, in my messaging functions.php file, I use prepared statements

Comment: `or "video/mpeg4"` @TheDoc (please ping like I did), isn't valid, it doesn't do anything. Edit: along with the other similar codes you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic you use in the `if( $file_type==....` is flawed - it will always equate to true. Consider:

```
$file_type='image/jpeg';

if( $file_type == "ximage/jpg" or "ximage/jpeg" or "ximage/png" or "ximage/PNG" or "ximage/JPG" or "ximage/JPEG"){
    echo('# this is Bogus #');
}

$filetypes=array( 'image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif');
if( in_array( strtolower( $file_type ), $filetypes ) )echo '# This is good #;';
```

This will output

```
# this is Bogus ## This is good #;
```

The first portion is clearly wrong - the use of `ximage/jpeg` etc should not validate

Comment: That's a long comment, IMHO. Which I already said in comments.